# String not getting split giving unrecognized selector error

Tags: iphone, nsstring

Trying to split the string in to array, but it is giving error "[__NSArrayI componentsSeparatedByString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x11741b20'". The string contains the value, that comes from first index of array then the string needs to be split and store in array.

This is array value.

```
mcommarr:(
":comment",
":comment",
":comment"

NSString *strr = [[NSString alloc]init];
strr = [self.mCommArr objectAtIndex:indexVal];
NSArray *arr2 = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Here is the complete method in which i am using this.

```
-(void)loadData:(int)indexVal;
{    
indexVal=serialIndexVal;
serialIndexVal++;

NSLog(@"arrLike:%d", [self.mArrLike count]);
NSLog(@"arrPid:%d", [self.mArrPid count]);

status = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"get"];
[self.mButtonsStatusDict setObject:status forKey:@"status"];

[self.mButtonsPidDict setObject:[self.mArrPid objectAtIndex:indexVal] forKey:@"pid"];


[self.activityIndicator startAnimating];

@try
{
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);

dispatch_async(queue, ^{

    NSString *status = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"get"];
    [self.mButtonsStatusDict setObject:status forKey:@"status"];
    [self.mButtonsPidDict setObject:[self.mArrPid objectAtIndex:indexVal] forKey:@"pid"];

    self.mButtonsCommentsDict = [MyEventApi showComments:self.mButtonsPidDict];

    self.mButtonsDict = [MyEventApi likeDislike:self.mButtonsUidDict post:self.mButtonsPidDict postStatus:self.mButtonsStatusDict];

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
         NSLog(@"buttons data dict:%@", self.mButtonsDict);

        if([self.mButtonsDict count] == 0)
        {
            NSLog(@"server problem no response");
            [self.mArrLike addObject: @"0"];
            [self.mArrDislike addObject: @"0"];
        }else{
        [self.mArrLike addObject: [self.mButtonsDict valueForKey:@"like"]];
        [self.mArrDislike addObject: [self.mButtonsDict valueForKey:@"dislike"]];
        }

        if([self.mButtonsCommentsDict count] == 0)
        {
            NSLog(@"server problem no response");
             [self.mCommArrTot addObject: @"0"];
        }
        else{
            self.dictComm = [self.mButtonsCommentsDict valueForKey:@"comments"];
            [self.mCommArr addObject:[self.dictComm valueForKey:@"comment"]];
            NSLog(@"count:%d",[self.mCommArr count]);
          //  NSString *strTot = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",tot];
           // [self.mCommArrTot addObject:strTot];
            NSLog(@"dictcomm:%@", self.dictComm );
            NSLog(@"mcommarr:%@", [self.mCommArr objectAtIndex:indexVal]);
            strr = [[NSString alloc]init];
            strr = [self.mCommArr objectAtIndex:indexVal];
            //NSString *strr = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.mCommArr objectAtIndex:indexVal]];
           // NSArray *arr1 = [self string:strr];

           // NSArray *splitArray=[self.mCommArr[0] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

             //[strr componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
           // NSLog(@"arrSep:%@", arr1);
            //int count = [arr1 count];
            //NSLog(@"arrcount:%d", count);
           // NSString *strTot = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",count];
            // [self.mCommArrTot addObject:strTot];
            //NSLog(@"mcommarrtot:%@", [self.mCommArrTot objectAtIndex:indexVal]);
        }
       // NSLog(@"arrLike:%@", [self.mArrLike objectAtIndex:indexVal]);
        // NSLog(@"arrDisLike:%@", [self.mArrLike objectAtIndex:indexVal]);

        [self.mPublicFriendTable reloadData];

    });
});
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"main: Caught %@: %@", [exception name], [exception reason]); 
}
@finally {

}
}
```

It get killed when try to split. Why so, i am not getting. If anyone has faced such situation please guide what is wrong her.

Comment: Please copy-paste the snippet from your code, as it reflects wrong string name: `str` as it should be `strr`. Also, I think you have misinterpreted `mcommarr`. print the exact values to get perfect answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string into an NSArray like below...

```
NSString *yourString = @"comment,comment,comment";
NSArray *strArray = [yourString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSLog(@"\n\n Array is ==>> %@",strArray);
```

Comment: array does not have static values, it is coming from server. SO, it varies.

Comment: i just give you an example dude... just put the value instead of my static value like... NSString *yourString = [yourArray objectAtIndex:0];

Comment: @iPhone hey try to retain that string like this... [strr retain]; and then use NSArray *arr2 = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@","]; try and let me know...

Comment: @iPhone till you have problem?? and also just NSLog(@"\n\n Array is ==>> %@",[yourArray objectAtIndex:0]); write this line and tell me what you get in console...

Comment: sure, i am editing question and posting more code in it. Then check.

Comment: what you get output on this line.. NSLog(@"mcommarr:%@", [self.mCommArr objectAtIndex:indexVal]); in console??

Comment: also what is the self.mCommArr ?? means if this is NSMutableArray then you alloc and init it in viewDidLoad or any where??

Comment: mcommarr:(
    ":comment",
    ":comment",
    ":comment"
)

Comment: ya it is nsm array, and alloc in viewdidload.

Comment: but here you can directly get it in NSArray like this ... NSArray *tempArray = [self.dictComm valueForKey:@"comment"];
            [tempArray retain];

Comment: here problem is that when you get value from objectAtIndex of self.mCommArr  it is return only one value which name is :comment you not get array... after use my above code you can directly use the array...

Comment: and also try with this.. NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.mCommArr objectAtIndex:indexVal]];

Comment: ok here try my above code and NSLog that array.. its get whole value which is index of mCommAr.. :)

Comment: I think the problem was only i was adding object in array from dictionary.

Comment: now it adds single element at each index no need of splitting. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> "[__NSArrayI componentsSeparatedByString:]:

Your error says you tried to send the above method to `NSArray`, which doesn't has.

As you want to split the array at index 0. you should probably do as :

```
NSArray *splitArray=[yourArray[0] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Here yourArray is the array that you get from Server.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *strr = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.mCommArr objectAtIndex:indexVal]];
NSArray *arr2 = [strr componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

I think you are passing `str` right now, which can be an array (as your error points out).
Let me know the results.